# How to return a single record from two tables if a certain date in either table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables each with a date field.  If EITHER table has a certain date, then return ONLY the single record from THAT corresponding table. This is close, but it always returns BOTH tables:

```
SELECT ruberic.teacherid,
       ruberic.date,
       coaching_interactions.teacherid,
       coaching_interactions.date
FROM   ruberic,
       coaching_interactions
WHERE  ruberic.date = '2016-12-13'
        OR coaching_interactions.date = '2016-12-13'
```

Comment: You are putting those tables side by side, that's clearly not what you want. Use `UNION`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Union`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html). It will also remove duplicates (if any):

```
SELECT ruberic.teacherid,
       ruberic.date,
FROM   ruberic 
WHERE  ruberic.date = '2016-12-13'

UNION 

SELECT coaching_interactions.teacherid,
       coaching_interactions.date
FROM   coaching_interactions
WHERE  coaching_interactions.date = '2016-12-13'
```

Comment: Awesome!  thanks Madhur that did it.  Also, in each SELECT statement I added a  'Ruberic Table' or 'Coaching Table' so I know where it came from.